# How to mock non-calls to object methods in Python unittest library

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I've got a really useful python method like this:

```
def stop_widget():
  original_widget = load_widget_from_file()
  if original_widget: 
    original_widget.close()
```

when I want to test it to make sure I called `close()`, I do:

```
@patch('load_widget_from_file')
def test_stop_widget_with_original_widget(self, lwff_mock):
    mock_widget = create_autospec(Widget)
    lwff_mock.return_value = mock_widget
    stop_widget()
    mock_widget.close.assert_called_once_with()
```

but what do I do when I want to test *not* calling `close` when the return value of `load_widget_from_file` doesn't evaluate to True?

If I tried making another unit test with:

```
@patch('load_widget_from_file')
def test_stop_widget_with_original_widget(self, lwff_mock):
    mock_widget = None
    lwff_mock.return_value = mock_widget
    stop_widget()
    mock_widget.close.assert_not_called()
```

this would blow up.

Comment: What about `assert_not_called`?

Comment: @larsks, I don't have an object instantiated with a function to call that on.

Comment: what happens if you just do `mock_widget = create_autospec(Widget)` in the second method, just like in the first method?

Comment: @rick, that fails because close is called (this would make it identical to the first case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a second mock object (instead of setting `mock_widget = None`), but the widget needs to be falsey to prevent the function from entering the if condition.

In Python, an object is always "truthy" unless is has a zero-length, or it has a [`__bool__` method that returns `False`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__):

> object.__bool__(self)
>
> Called to implement truth value testing and the built-in operation `bool()`; should return `False` or `True`. When this method is not defined, `__len__()` is called, if it is defined, and the object is considered true if its result is nonzero. If a class defines neither `__len__()` nor `__bool__()`, all its instances are considered true.

Probably the "right way" to add a `__bool__` method to your mock object would be to [use `MagicMock`](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/unittest.mock.html#magicmock-and-magic-method-support), which comes with many of the Python "magic methods" pre-defined. But you'll also have to change the return value to `False`, like so:

```
@patch('load_widget_from_file')
def test_stop_widget_with_original_widget(self, lwff_mock):
    mock_widget = MagicMock()
    mock_widget.__bool__.return_value = False
    lwff_mock.return_value = mock_widget
    stop_widget()
    mock_widget.close.assert_not_called()
```

Comment: Yeah, the first way doesn't work - __bool__ is not defined in the original class so I think create_autospec doesn't go in and make it (at least not the version I'm running Python 3.5.1, I looked at some changelogs for the unittest framework and it looked like someone implemented some magicmethod for __bool__ a long time ago, but I don't see docs for it.

Comment: yeah I didn't bother testing. deleted the first idea- not sure why it isn't working but whatever.

Comment: I tried the way you have mentioned but for Python 3.6 the above solution was not working.Changed the code   lwff_mock.return_value.__bool__.return_value = False   and it worked.